# Bitbucket pipelines using git submodules foreach

Tags: git, deployment, git-submodules, bitbucket-pipelines, git-ftp

I want to deploy my repository with git-ftp (as many of my client’s hosting plans don’t include SSH access) to my staging environment where WordPress is included as a submodule. This was my first attempt with Bitbucket pipelines:

```
image: php:7.1

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
    - step:
        deployment: staging
        script:
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
          - git ftp init -vv --user $sftp_user --passwd $sftp_passwd $sftp_path
```

It works perfectly fine and transfers all the files to my server, despite the fact that it doesn’t deploy the WordPress repository but an empty placeholder file.

As it says [here](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/issues/295) the support for submodules doesn’t work all the time but there is a workaround using

```
git submodule foreach git [init|push|catchup]
```

I tried all the steps manually using Bash and it worked:

```
$ git ftp init --user $sftp_user --passwd $sftp_passwd -vv $sftp_path
$ git submodule foreach 'git ftp init -vv $sftp_user --passwd $sftp_passwd -vv $sftp_path/$path/'
```

But when I try to apply this workaround to my bitbucket-pipelines.yml the submodule command foreach doesn’t seem to work at all… Testing the command only outputs

```
git submodule foreach 'echo $path'
+ git submodule foreach echo 'echo $path'
```

---

1. Does anyone know a better workaround?
2. Why is submodule (+ foreach) not working? Or is it?
3. The command should give you [access to several variables](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#git-submodule-foreach--recursiveltcommandgt), do Bitbucket’s repository variables override/block these?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For the second point of your question: yes it is working fine, the line with `+` simply lists the command which was executed. If no error was displayed it executed just fine.

As for the third point, yes this variable will be overwritten by bitbucket IF you set a variable $path, because of course that would overwrite it. If you don't do this it should work fine, however I noticed the following in the git documentation:

> Note that to avoid conflicts with $PATH on Windows, the $path variable is now a deprecated synonym of $sm_path variable. Any submodules defined in the superproject but not checked out are ignored by this command.

So you would have to check them out in order for them to be printed. When you used this command locally I suppose the submodules are checked out which is why the command does work there.

A work around so you don't have to check them out in bitbucket pipelines is to use the following command:

`git config --file .gitmodules --get-regexp path | awk '{ print $2 }'`

I hope this helps you

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer! :) I didn’t mention it in my initial post but I tried to echo the $path variable but nothing was listed during the process, neither did `git submodule foreach…` seem to work. I tried $sm_path as well — still nothing. I will check your recommended command event though I’m not an expert and don't know exactly what the command is doing. Thanks so far! :)

Comment: Unfortunatelly not… Which doesn’t mean that it doesn’t work per se but I just found a better workflow using composer.